# What is the meaning of "Key Deletion" operation?

Tags: encryption, key-management

In the context of Key Management and encryption/decryption, what does "Deleting a Key" mean exactly? What are the implications of "Key Deletion", in terms of:

- Decryption of the old data (i.e. data encrypted already using this Key)
- Re-using the Key by creating it again (either accidentally or on-purpose)
- Storage of the Key (should the Key be purged or just simply be marked as "Deleted")?

In other words, assuming there is an encryption application client that uses Keys from a Key Manager, and if there is any data that was encrypted using a Key, what should be done if a user requests to delete a Key? Are there any scenarios possible? Or shouldn't the key be allowed to be deleted at all?

Also, what should be done if a user deletes a Key and then later he wants to create the same Key again? What are the best practices here? Should the user be prevented? Are there any standards?

and, Last but not the least, when a Key Manager deletes a Key, what is normally happens in terms of the actual storage? Should the Key be purged, or should it be retained? Of course, I understand that this is somehow related to the previous questions as if re-creating a deleted Key is not to be allowed, the Key must not be purged. So, my question is, how the things are normally done in a Key Manager? or if there is any standard definition for this management operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with a product, check the vendor's product documentation for the precise meaning they have given the terms, or contact the vendor and ask them.  If you are writing your own security policies, create a glossary and define your terms to mean what you need.

For your examples, I would define the specific needs and use cases, and give each its own term.  I might define them like this:

- Key Deletion: to erase all copies of a key within a defined environment, so that the key is no longer recoverable in that environment.
- Key Destruction: to securely erase all copies of the key in all environments such that the data encrypted with it can never be recovered.
- Key Injection: to introduce a new key into a secure operating environment.
- Key Recovery: to restore a previously deleted key to an operating environment using Key Injection.

When you buy a new hardware security module, you might need to use key injection to first put the keys into it.  You might use key deletion inside a tamper-detecting housing of a hardware security module, so that if someone tries to open the case, the key is protected.  Key recovery would be used to restore the keys in a secure environment, after you've fixe the case.  And you would use key destruction if you had a sensitive document that you needed to shred, such as expired records.

Answer (score 2):

I hate saying this but, depends on the context.

If you have a lot of documents depending on one key, when a key expire you can do one of the following:

1. Recypher your documents, so you can truly delete your old key.
2. Keep old documents cyphered with the old keys, so you just mark your key as deleted and reuse it when you have to obtain those documents.

About "re-creating" the key, it will be very difficult, if not impossible, to regenerate the very same key again if you use standar creation mechanisms, so don't rely on that.

When truly deleting a key, the best practice is purging it (shred it) if you have an old HD, if you have a new HD either you just delete it or on SSD you are screwed or destroy it and buy a new one (you will have to make a decision depending on the system and its security requisites).